# Parsing of a decimal type in C# fails unexpectedly

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, xml-parsing

I'm parsing an XML document from a web-service which returns an array of objects.

An object has fields that contain floating-point values, it looks like so:

```
<Valute ID="R01010">
<NumCode>036</NumCode>
<CharCode>AUD</CharCode>
<Nominal>1</Nominal>
<Name>Australian Dollar</Name>
<Value>14,4200</Value>
</Valute>
```

I am successfully reading the document into an `XDocument` object like so:

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
using (var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet)))
{
    XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument();
    try
    {
        xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd());

        DesiredDate = DateTime.ParseExact(xmlDoc.Element("ValCurs").Attribute("Date").Value, "dd.MM.yyyy", new CultureInfo("ru-RU"));

        result = new List<CBRItem>();

        foreach (var valuteElement in xmlDoc.Element("ValCurs").Elements("Valute"))
        {
            CBRItem item = CBRItem.FromXElement(valuteElement);

            if (item != null)
            {
                result.Add(item);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not convert from Valute XML element:\n" + valuteElement.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

And I process each object in the array like so:

```
public static CBRItem FromXElement(XElement elem)
{
    CBRItem result = new CBRItem();

    try
    {
        result.ID = elem.Attribute("ID").Value;
        result.NumCode = elem.Element("NumCode").Value;
        result.CharCode = elem.Element("CharCode").Value;
        result.Nominal = short.Parse(elem.Element("Nominal").Value, new CultureInfo("ru-RU"));
        result.Name = elem.Element("Name").Value;
        result.Value = decimal.Parse(elem.Element("Value").Value, new CultureInfo("ru-RU"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }

    return result;
}
```

I've debugged my code an verified that the `XElement` objects that I pass into the `FromXElement` functions are filled with appropriate data (like mentioned in the beginning).

But I'm getting a `System.FormatException` on the `decimal` parsing line

```
result.Value = decimal.Parse(elem.Element("Value").Value, new CultureInfo("ru-RU"));
```

On some PCs but not mine or the one I have at work.

This is really weird and I've even specifid the culture in order to eliminate the parsing error which could occur because the `NumberDecimalSeparator` being not a comma in the current culture. (The culture is `ru-RU` because the web-service is Russian and I think that's the appropriate choice in that case)

**So, what could be causing this issue?**

Comment: How do you expect `14,4200` to come out? If "," is the decimal, then it would be 14,42 - so far so good. But if it is explicitly _not_ the decimal, then what is it? The 1000-Sep? Then it should be `144,200` ...

Comment: @Fildor, the web-service uses `,` as it's decimal separator

Comment: AH, then I misunderstood the last paragraph, sorry.

Comment: Does it use a 1000-sep? Does the API have a documentation, where it is stated, what culture it is exactly?

Comment: @Fildor no, I din't find anything about the 1000-sep or culture. Actually, here's the service example: http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp?date_req=21/11/2000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly the `NumberDecimalSeparator` is set to something different than `,` on your system for the culture `ru-RU`.

You can explicitly set the `NumberDecimalSeparator` on the `CultureInfo`:

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";

...

result.Value = decimal.Parse(elem.Element("Value").Value, cultureInfo);
```

Comment: @lilbroomstick: just seen your edit, that the problem does not occur on your own machine, but just on some others. Probably on those the system culture ru-RU is configured differently